# Text and FontAwesome alignment in a Bootstrap 5 button

Tags: font-awesome, bootstrap-5

I am trying to figure out how to do something with a Bootstrap 5 button.  I would like to be able to have the text label of the button left-justified and the FontAwesome icon right-justified.  If I use a fixed-width button, how do I make sure it scales according to screen size along with all of the other content?
Here's my button now, but the icon is on the wrong side, and nothing is justified:

```
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></span>
                Learn More
            </button>
```

Thank you in advance for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

```css
button {
  min-width: 20vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success d-flex justify-content-between">
  <div class="col-10">Learn More</div>
  <div class="col-2"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
</button>
```